# HAML not being loaded in Rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, haml, passenger

I'm using Capistrano to deploy to a VM I've got set up (long story). The VM is running Ubuntu Server, apache, phusion passenger, ruby 1.9.1 (installed via rvm).

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Forked it to hack onto it later, there are a few possibly improvements, such as adding different message types with default segments
gem 'ruby-hl7', git: "git@github.com:chintanparikh/ruby-hl7.git"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Here's the production.log for when I make a request to `/`

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Started GET "/" for 192.168.56.1 at 2013-06-07 12:48:54 -0400
Processing by MessagesController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 90ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template messages/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/var/www/ThunderMountain/releases/20130610165658/app/views"
):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3081847909475578688__process_action__4282653674359148431__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2554153809732348193__call__569526256387911806__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

From `:handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}` it looks like it's not loading the haml handler for some reason.

If I go into `current/` and run `bundle install | grep haml`, I get:

```
± bundle install | grep haml
Using haml (4.0.3)
Using haml-rails (0.4)
```

Also, `shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems` has

```
haml-4.0.3
haml-rails-0.4
```

so it looks the gems are definitely installed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the issue could be, or on how to debug further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haml should not be included in the assets group as those are assets not being sent to production by default.  If you move it out of the assets group it should behave as expected.

Comment: I'm curious about what you're using HL7 for as well.  You're obviously writing something to do with the medical field as I've used it a couple times as well.  I've updated the ruby-hl7 gem here: https://github.com/guttermonkey/ruby-hl7 to update it to the latest gemspec and rake versions.

Comment: Sweet, cheers I'll give that a go. I'm writing an app to simulate a hospital for the company I'm interning for. Basically just going to be sending ADT and CCD feeds

Comment: Feel free to let me know if you need some assistance with the HL7, I've got a couple Ruby/Rails apps in production that do HL7 messaging back and forth.

Comment: That'd be amazing, I'll definitely take you up on that offer once I've got this deployment stuff sorted out. Moving it out of assets worked, now I've got some kind of assets precompiling error. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why anything in the assets group isn't sent to production by default? Doesn't seem right, surely you need assets in production

Comment: @guttermoney, I'm having some trouble architecturally integrating the gem into my RoR app. Any chance I can contact you by email?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  The assets group is specifically for gems that are used on the fly during dev & test.  For production environments those items are compiled via the assets pipeline and become static files (so SASS gets compiled down to CSS).  Feel free to send me an email at guttermnky@gmail.com with your HL7 stuff.  I'll respond to that faster anyways. :)

Comment: No worries. Thanks, definitely will. Appreciate the help!